# javac compiles classes with default access modifiers even if the file name is different

Tags: java, javac

Why javac compiles classes with default modifiers even if the file name is different and why it does not when the access modifiers are public, private or protected?
eg: file name: Test
    Content of file
    class foo{}

it gets compiled without error and if I add public, private or protected infront of class it is not getting compiled can any one explain why its so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two rules

- If you declare a type as `public` then the filename should be same type can be a `class` or an `interface`
- There cannot be a `private` or `protected` outer class.

The answer for why for first point is that it is the way java specification is defined.
You can't declare an outer class as private because it won't server any purpose at all.

- You can have as types in a source file as you like but there can be only one public type and if there is a public type, the name of the file must match public type.

Comment: is there any reason why creators of java gave an exception in the case of classes with default modifiers?

Comment: Because classes have to be visible in the package. `default` access level means they are visible in that package

Comment: I was asking about why they gave exception for classes with default modifier in the case of filename